# How can I make http call to DialogFlow V2 using simple ajax jQuery?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, dialogflow-es

I have been using DialogFlow v1 before using simply jquery and it was pretty straigh forward working!

Now that I have to switch to V2 I am stuck on how to keep somehow same code but just modify with the V2!

I have been looking at this client library for V2:
https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2#using-the-client-library

But I dont wanna use Node.js I just dont want to do somthing like node server.js to run the app, also I am not sure if I can mix jQuery with Node.js.

My previous code v1 looked like this:

```
fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    // cache: 'no-cache',
    // credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + configs.accessToken,
    },
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrer: 'no-referrer',
})
    .then(response => response.json()) // parses response to JSON
```

Well I swtiched to ES6 for making http request for dialogflow but I would want the same code to use for V2, is this possible? Also I can no longer see access token for v2, how are we suppose to handle the auth for http calls?

I am really confused with the new V2 and since we switched to Enterprise Edition Account it is a must for us to use v2 and it kinda sucks!

Edit:
I am checking this example from documentation:

```
  POST https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/project-name/agent/intents

    Headers:
    Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)
    Content-Type: application/json

    POST body:
    {
        'displayName': 'StartStopwatch',
        'priority': 500000,
        'mlEnabled': true,
        'trainingPhrases': [
            {
                'type': 'EXAMPLE',
                'parts': [
                    {
                        'text': 'start stopwatch'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        'action': 'start',
        'messages': [
            {
                'text': {
                    'text': [
                        'Stopwatch started'
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
    }
```

But I am somehow confused on this part: `Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)` where do I get access-token?

I have already done this part:  gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file= which I have no idea what is it doing after activating! I was hoping I would get back some access-token from this, but there seem to be nothing just a message that says Activated  Service...

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm trying to find a way to have a js chat popup communicate directly with DialogFlow, but their documentation is a mess... I'm not sure it's possible without having a middleware (like a NodeJS server)... Security over ease-of-use... But to this level it's ridiculous... I feel it'll be faster to find another service and abandon Dialogflow...

Comment: @Yoh I had to create a middleware as  Nodejs service that would handle auth and communicate with DealogFlow API. For v1 I didnt have to do this. Yeah I also share the same opinion. too much for this!

Answer (score 2):

To use Dialogflow V2 API with browser AJAX just like V1, there is no simple way, unless you have the access token. I've run into same issue and figured out it can't be done without using their client libraries (SDK) or "google-oauth-jwt". In my example i used nodejs - google-oauth-jwt package which provides "access token" for my application which was used for browser AJAX calls. You don't have to use their nodejs SDK library, in case, you're handling logic on client side.

Setup Instructions:

1.Configure V2 API from V1 on the dialogflow account, follow the migration guide. Download the JSON file which has a unique email and key values. You might want to grant access to your application by registering the domains.

2.Create a nodejs application and use "google-oauth-jwt" to get the access token. Also, make this as a service to call it before hand to have the access token ready before making any ajax calls. Here is sample code:

```
app.get("/your_sample_web_service_to_get_access_token", (req, res, next) => {
new Promise((resolve) => {
    tokens.get({
            //find this email value from the downloaded json
            email: 'xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
            //find this key value from the downloaded json
            key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxx',
            //specify the scopes you wish to access: as mentioned in dialogflow documentation
            scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
        },
        (err, token) => {
            //rest api response
            res.json({
                "access_token": token
            });
            resolve(token);
        }
    );
});
});
```

3.From your client JavaScript, make an AJAX call using the access token you get from above nodejs application. Here is the sample code:

```
app.service('chatbot', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    this.callAPI = function (user_entered_query) {
        //I used detectintent REST API endpoint: find the project name from your account.
        var endpoint = "https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/xxx/agent/sessions/123456789:detectIntent";
        var data = JSON.stringify({queryParams:{}, query_input:{text:{text:user_entered_query,language_code:"en-US"}},outputAudioConfig:{},inputAudio:""});
        var headers = {
            //use the token from nodejs service
            "Authorization": "Bearer " +$rootScope.token
        };
        return $http.post(_url, _data, {"headers": headers});
    }
});
```

Comment: Can someone please edit the code format. I'm using Ctrl+k, but, it won't format.