# If our app code is on Firebase, should the code calling Dialogflow V2 APIs be inside client side javascript file or in Node Index.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, api, dialogflow-es, google-apis-explorer

Our frontend javascript code calling Dialogflow V1 APIs has been working great inside web frontend javascript file such as Main.js and not in Index.js.   Now we need to replace  V1 APIs with  V2 APIs;

But, our researches show that lots of sample code to call V2 APIs are placed in Node Index.js such as the following code and the following tutorial:
https://medium.com/@tzahi/how-to-setup-dialogflow-v2-authentication-programmatically-with-node-js-b37fa4815d89

```
// Instantiate a DialogFlow client.

const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({

 projectId,

  keyFilename: credentials_file_path,

});
```

## My researches results below answered some of my Q on this. The following posts show this point:

Dialogflow V2 APIs forced web apps to call its APIs through server code such as Node Index.js and not from Ajax call.
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627057/how-to-make-http-call-on-dialogflow-v2-using-javascript-ajax-call`

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633291/how-can-i-make-http-call-to-dialogflow-v2-using-simple-ajax-jquery?rq=1`

## But the above posts are around one year ago. I wish to verify this point: Does the current Dialogflow V2 APIs have the same requirements as the above?

Any thoughts and suggestions on this will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by regular javascript file or in Index.js?

Comment: "regular javascript file" means this: Not Index.js file

Comment: `.js` extension it self says it is Javascript file